# Can an individual in California file a small claims case and NOT serve the defendant (or defer the serving)?

Tags: california, small-claims-court, service

Does California allow a plaintiff to file a small claims case and either not serve the defendant or defer the serving until some time in the future (perhaps the plaintiff has 6 months to serve the defendant)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Service is not optional is California, see [the court page](https://www.courts.ca.gov/selfhelp-serving.htm) on service. The specific rule, [Rule 3.110](https://www.courts.ca.gov/documents/title_3.pdf), says that

> The complaint must be served on all named defendants and proofs of
>   service on those defendants must be filed with the court within 60
>   days after the filing of the complaint. When the complaint is amended
>   to add a defendant, the added defendant must be served and proof of
>   service must be filed within 30 days after the filing of the amended
>   complaint.